# French equivalents of "a double bind"

Tags: anglais, allemand

We were having a conversation in German, and I was wondering how the same idea is commonly/idiomatically expressed in French.

> Er steckte ganz schön **in der Zwickmühle** -- ich kann ihm den Weg, den er einschlug, nicht verübeln.

Here I was talking about a **double bind** he found himself in -- due to the conflicting nature of the two choices presented to him, it will prove to be a no-win situation for him anyway, whichever path he decides to take in the end.

Though not a literal rendering, the first French phrasing that sprang to mind was:

> Il était **dans une situation très délicate**. Je ne peux pas lui en vouloir des choix qu’il a faits.

Comment: The psychological term gets translated as [double contrainte](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_contrainte), but I'm not sure it's the exact same idea you're talking about.

Comment: @MatthewTowers *Double contrainte* (or *injonction paradoxale*) is a scientific term, it covers a much narrower scope than ["double bind"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/double-bind). It would not be appropriate here.

Answer (score 3):

Vu la situation que tu décris ("double bind", "no-win situation") où en fait il n'avait pas de choix réel je proposerais :

- Il était dans/face à une **situation sans issue**.
- Il était pris/se trouvait **dans une impasse**.

Et mieux encore **dans une double impasse** (merci @WoJ).

> Le gouvernement semble dans une double impasse : pas de programme cohérent et structuré et, en même temps, le besoin impérieux d’ouvrir un maximum de chantiers pour maintenir l’illusion de la transformation du pays.  ([*Contrepoints*](https://www.contrepoints.org/2018/04/20/314438-sncf-notre-dame-des-landes-le-pire-des-compromis) 20/04/18)

« Il était coincé » que propose @petitrien reflète la même idée (quand on est coincé c'est qu'on n'a pas d'issue), c'est juste une question de niveau de langue, c'est un petit peu plus familier.

Un autre possibilité :

- Il se trouvait dans une **situation inextricable**.

Pour moi cette solution implique qu'il est très très difficile de s'en sortir mais n'en exclut pas la possibilité.

Cependant *In eine Zwickmühle stecken* n'implique pas que la situation est « sans issue » et donc si on oublie *double bind* et *no-win* d'autres propositions sont possibles.
Il me semble que la traduction la plus courante et la plus neutre de *in eine Zwickmühle stecken* c'est :

- être/se trouver dans une situation difficile.

D'autres options sont possibles.

- Il était dans une situation très délicate.

convient et le choix de l'adjectif ajoute un jugement moral de la part du locuteur (ici de sympathie).

- Il se trouvait dans une situation très embarrassante.
- Il se trouvait face à un dilemme/pris dans un dilemme.

Attention dilemme ne peut être employé qu'en cas de choix binaire, ce qui est le cas dans la situation décrite dans la question.

Dans un registre plus familier on peut envisager :

- Il était piégé.

Comment: I think that *impasse* suggests that there is no choice, or that the choice made earlier was not the good one. *Après avoir essayé les deux solutions il s'est retrouvé dans une impasse* | *elle a choisi de couper le fil rouge, le compteur a accéléré et maintenant elle était prise dans une impasse: impossible de couper le fil vert qui avait été avalé par la bombe*. Otherwise very nice answer (+1)

Comment: On peut éventuellement parler d'un dilemme (ou choix) cornélien, selon le contexte. Pour l'impasse, on voit aussi "dans une double impasse" parfois.

Comment: @WoJ In  Good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what I'd say in the situation you describe is :

- Il était coincé. Je ne peux pas lui en vouloir des choix qu’il a faits.

Answer (score 1):

There is an idiom that may match in many contexts , but that belongs to a colloquial level of language : *avoir le cul entre deux chaises*.

Comment: *Avoir le cul entre deux chaises*  (or in a non colloquial way *être assis entre deux chaises*) doesn't necessarily imply that you have to make a decision but just that you are in an uneasy/unstable situation ([TLF](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaise) *Se trouver dans une situation incertaine*). I'd say it's closer to "be sitting on a fence" than to "be in a double bind". It may be that you are just unwilling to make a decision.

Comment: @Laure: interesting, I always used that expression to denote a degree of urgency to make a decision (and move the *cul* to one of the two *chaises*). But you are correct: is is just a matter of being uncomfortable with a choice, without the proximity of the choice.

Answer (score 0):

> Il était confronté à un dilemme insoluble. Sa situation était défavorable quel que soit son choix.

Answer (score 0):

1) *Il avait le choix entre Charybde et Scylla* ou *Il était entre Charybde et Scylla* (*Il se trouvait entre...*).

Je l'ajoute à la liste parce que je trouve ça joli, mais je recommande plutôt les autres réponses, car l'expression la plus courante qui ressemble est "tomber de Charybde en Scylla" qui n'a pas le même sens.

2) *Choisir entre la peste et le choléra*.